# Having problems with VBA Find and Match functions

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a macro that will search through column A to find "Award:".  I would like this stored so that I can use the row in a copy paste function later. There are empty cells in between each instance of Award:. When I use a message box for either of the row variables, I get 0 returned
This is what I have so far

```
Dim StartReport As Range
Dim EndReport As Range
Dim StartRow As Integer
Dim EndRow As Integer
Set StartReport = Worksheets("Grant Expense").Range("A:A").Find("Award:", LookAt:=xlPart)
Set EndReport = Worksheets("Grant Expense").Range("C:C").Find("Total Costs", LookAt:=xlPart)
StartRow = StartReport.Row
EndRow = EndReport.Row
Range(Cells(1, StartRow), Cells(17, EndRow)).Select
```

Comment: Do you get any results if you use the built-in Find dialog?

Comment: I do. It cycles the cells I am looking for, but I need to have the colon in it otherwise, "Award" appears in other cells.

Comment: If anyone else has this problem, I am performing the find in merged cells. The find function works if I make the range all the merged cells. In this case, Range("A:C").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Find function, for some reason, sometimes, will not return anything if that is the only text in the cell. 
Ensure all filters are off, so you could add:

```
If Worksheets("Grant Expense").AutoFilterMode Then 
    Worksheets("Grant Expense").ShowAllData
End If
```

But I think you may have mixed up Cells. it is row first, then column, so:

```
Range(Cells(StartRow, 1), Cells(EndRow, 17)).Select
```

I have found the solution, I do not know why, but this works correctly:

```
Set StartRow = (Worksheets("Grant Expense").Range("A:C").Find("Award:"))
Set endrow = (Worksheets("Grant Expense").Range("C:D").Find("Total Costs"))
```

However. Find will start AFTER the upper most left cell in the Range, which means your first Award is not the start.  To remedy this insert another row in your workbook.  And remember to use the correct Range:

```
Range(Cells(StartRow, 1), Cells(EndRow, 17)).Select
```

Comment: I tried the find function in excel and returned the results I am looking for. Is that what you were suggesting?

Comment: So the find button is working, but not when you use the find function in vba?

Comment: Correct.  I also found that one of my problems was using thisworkbook instead of activeworkbook for Wb.  But I am still getting "Nothing" as a result of the searches.

Comment: I added a colon to one of my cells and searched for it, using the full string, and it returned.  Have you used breakpoints to ensure the sub is even hitting the set?  If it never goes to the set, then of course it will be nothing.

Comment: "Have you used breakpoints to ensure the sub is even hitting the set?"
I don't understand this question.

Comment: Rather, I understand he question, but not how to make sure it is hitting the set.

Comment: You can set breakpoints by clicking in the gray barrier to the left of the border.  This will pause the sub when it reaches that line.  This is very helpful in debugging.  Put breakpoints next to Set StartReport, Set EndReport, and StartRow = StartReport.Row.  Then run the sub.  If Set StartReport goes yellow, it means it did hit the Set StartReport.  Then press the play button again, and it will go to Set EndReport.  At this point hover over StartReport on the previous line.  See if it says nothing.  Then press play again and see if EndReport says nothing.

Comment: Ok, I added the breaks.  I've been stepping through with F8, at the StartRow = StartReport.Row I get a runtime Error Object variable or ith block Variable not set. I figure this is because the finds are giving me nothing.

Comment: I don't understand why it is not working, I cannot replicate your issue.  As the excel find button works, record the macro, then run the find button function, then take the code from that macro and use it in your sub.  If you don't have a lot of rows, you can use a for each loop, but if you have a lot of rows, it will be way too slow.

Comment: Look at my edit of my answer, this is the final answer.  I have done what I said in my edit, and it works exactly as you want.

Comment: Beautiful.  Thank you for your help.  One thing, I edited my code, but if anyone searches this, would you please edit it so that it says Startreport and EndReport?

Comment: Sure sorry it took so long

Answer (score 0):

Ha ha ha. I'm dumb.  You didn't specifiy the parameter name for the value you're searcing for.  Change `"Award:"` to `What:="Award:"`

To make it absolutely foolproof you can change the entire find command with:

```
.Find(What:="Award:", After:=Sheets("Grant Expense").Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False)
```

Then you can use `.FindNext` to find the next occurance.

Comment: I added that, but I am still getting "Nothing"


'    Set StartReport = Wb.Worksheets("Grant Expense").Range("A:A").Find(What:="Award:", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)

Comment: Without seeing the actual workbook this question is almost impossible to answer.  There are many reasons why this could be failing and it would take a very long time to go therough all of them here.  Can you share your workbook with me?

Comment: Yes, how should I do that?

Comment: Post the file on a file sharing site and provide the link here.

Comment: The purpose is to get each report onto its own sheet, which I can name by project ID. I have to insert some formulas on each report, so that's why I would like them on separate sheets.

Comment: I updated the answer.  Please try what I wrote and then give me the green checkmark.

Comment: Sorry, I already updated my code to include that, to no avail. It currently looks like this:   Set StartReport = Wb.Worksheets("Grant Expense").Range("A:A").Find(What:="Award:", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)      I also tried the code Geoff Lentsch provided.

Comment: I used your code and only changed that and it worked.  Is there more code that you didn't post.  Your workbook contains no code.

Comment: I don't know what else to tell you.  I tried the solutions that I provided in the workbook that you shared and your originally-posted code (from this site) worked with the workbook that you provided.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I'm not sure what happened, but it's working now.

Comment: If it's working, please mark this post with the green checkmark to show that it has a correct answer.

Comment: Actually the other responder had the right answer. The cell containing Award: was merged across A:C so the range in the find had to be "A:C" The same issue occurred in the other find as well.
Thank you for your time and effort though.